# Server name doesn't exit in current context in crystal report(visual studio 2010)

Tags: c#

I am trying to generate crystal report but i am getting error for server name.

Here is my code,

```
 rptDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("C:\\Users\\intlpos\\documents\\visual studio 2010\\Projects\\FormCrystalReport\\FormCrystalReport\\SubProductReport.rpt"));
```

error message is `Server name doesn't exit in current context.` I am using Visual Studio 2010.

Can anyone help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting this error at run time or at compile time?

Comment: Does the error occur at compile time or runtime? Btw, you have asked 15 questions on SO and accepted answers for none of them. This is usually considered rather poor etiquette. Please consider reviewing your previous questions and/or working on your questions more before you post them.

Comment: @Rushabh Shah: What was the answer? Would you please share with the community?

Comment: @RushabhShah Don't take this the wrong way, but are you unable or unwilling to accept answers? It is customary to click the checkmark next to one answer that you feel helped you most for each question. Revisit your old questions and accept some answers, please.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Server.MapPath() takes a virtual path, not a physical path, as an input.  So you would use

`Server.MapPath(@"Users/intlpos/documents/visual studio 2010/<<snip>>/filename.asp")` to convert the virtual path to the physical path.

[Take a look here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210417074237/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/121799-1.shtml) for better info.